# How's this monkey patching mutating the method already read?

Tags: javascript

How come the code below returns 33?

```
// beta.js
function number() {
  return 22
}
module.exports = { number };

// alfa.js
function alfa() {
  return beta.number();
}
module.exports = alfa;

const alfa = require("../alfa");
const beta = require("../beta");

beta.number = () => 33

alfa()
>> 33
```

Put in other words: how is it even possible that we can override the `beta` declaration inside `alfa`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? What would prevent it?

Comment: that's just a reference to a global variable.  and const only prevents reassignment of the _reference_ stored in variable beta to the beta object.  the object beta itself  can be mutated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// beta.js
function number() {
  return 22
}
module.exports = { beta };
```

I'm assuming this was supposed to be `module.exports = { number };`

Anyway, all that's going on is that there's an object, and a property on that object is being modified. The `alfa` file has a reference to that object, so if someone modifies the object, then the `alfa` file will "see" those changes.

The imports make it a bit harder to follow since it's spread across multiple files, but basically you're doing the following:

```js
const b = {
  number: () => 22
}

// creating a new reference to the object. This does *not* copy the object.
const a = b; 
// modifying the one and only object, using the b reference
b.number = () => 33;
// calling the function on that object, using the a reference
console.log(a.number());
```